# PoEdit doesn't recognize php dgettext function

Tags: poedit, php-gettext

How can I configure PoEdit to recognize PHP dgettext function ?

Note that I know about the Configure->Keywords part, but how am I suppose to indicate that the translation is in the second parameter of the function ?

Anyone got poEdit work with dgettext ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the :2 xgettext option, so the keyword that must be added in PoEdit is:
dgettext:2

the :2 specify to read the 2nd parameter.
If I would need to read the 2nd and 3rd, it would be: :2,3

Note that I had another bug, by default, dgettext is supported by xgettext (and poEdit) as it's a standard C/C++ gettext function.

Hope this will help